# error: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't get this context stuff at all I guess...  take a look at this snippet from the Create action of a controller:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Individual target = db.Individuals.Where(i => i.ID == Target.ID).First();

    target.LocationId = Destination.ID;
    db.Entry(target).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    if (newPair != null)
    {
        db.Pairs.Add(newPair);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The first `SaveChanges();` works just fine, the record is updated in the db. But the `.Add()` line just before the second `SaveChanges();` results in the error `An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.`

`newPair` is a new instance of the `Pair` class created a few lines above, and `db` is an instance of my db context created at the controller level, as in:

```
public class MoveController : Controller
{
    private ShepherdContext db = new ShepherdContext();
......
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Does your `newPair` reference other entities?

Comment: Yes! That was it! I was doing this: `newPair.Individual1 = Target` when I should have been doing this `newPair.IndividualId = Target.Id`  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to MVC & Entity frame work. I got same problem after fighting a lot
This solution worked for me. Hope it can be useful for you guys.

```
var mediaItem = db.MediaItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == mediaItemViewModel.Id);
    mediaItem.Name = mediaItemViewModel.Name;
    mediaItem.Description = mediaItemViewModel.Description;
    mediaItem.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    mediaItem.FileName = mediaItem.FileName;
    mediaItem.Size = KBToMBConversion(mediaItemViewModel.Size);
    mediaItem.Type = mediaItem.Type;

//db.Entry(mediaItem).State = EntityState.Modified;// coment This line
db.SaveChanges();
```

Cause you are reading the the whole object from db and holding it in the current context and when you try to modify the entity state its tells you already one entity attached to the current context. just call save changes it will save it.